# Move Newsletter Subscription form before footer Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, newsletter

I'm using magento 2, and I'm building a theme with the blank theme parent. What I'm trying to do is to move the subscription form, from the footer, before the footer, so it's not into the footer container. I have tryed several codes like:

```
<move element="form.subscribe" destination="content" before="page-footer" />
    <move element="form.subscribe" destination="footer" before="content"/>

    <move element="form.subscribe" destination="body" before="footer"/>
```

into the `default_head_blocks.xml`

but nothing to do.. any idea?

Comment: Are you not able to move the form.subscribe or you not able to find the correct destination?

Comment: I'm not able to find the correct destination.. I have also copied the content from subscribe.phtml into a block, and added it throught a widget in different destinations, but can't find one, without the padding or margin aside.. I want this newsletter to have 100% width, before the footer..

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code, may this will help you:-

```
<move element="form.subscribe" destination="footer" before="-"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code may it will helps you,

```
        <referenceContainer name="container.name.subscribe">
         <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="form.subscribe" as="subscribe" template="subscribe.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
```

or you can move on Content area:

```
<move element="container.name.subscribe" destination="content"/>
```