# Magento 2: Adding a template file before the page footer (invalid template file error)

Tags: magento2, template

I am trying to add a template file above my footer to show a subscribe form.

In my template I have created a file `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`. Here's the contents:

```
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                    name="prefooter.subscribe"
                    template="Magento_Theme::footer-subscribe.phtml" />

                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="ofihudui">
                  <action method="setTitle"><argument name="title" xsi:type="string">TEST</argument></action>
                  <action method="setBlockId"><argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">test</argument></action>
                </block>

            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I have also created the file `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/template/footer-subscribe.phtml` and here's the contents:

```
<h1>test</h1>
```

The page will show the second block fine, but when I try to add the `prefooter.subscribe` block Magento gives me this error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Magento_Theme::footer-subscribe.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'prefooter.subscribe'
```

Is it because I have the file in the wrong place? I'm not sure what to do here, it seems like it should work to me.

Comment: Have you got solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think u should try naming the phtml file footer_subscribe.phtml instead of footer-subscribe.phtml

Comment: Ahh damn. I just realised the problem... the `template` dir should be `templates`

Comment: @Callum No if you change your `template` to`templates` then also your problem is not solve.

Comment: Have u tried clearing cache and reindexing after changing the template to templates

Comment: Yes there is a problem with `template` to `templates` but also one another problem as per error check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per your query i found that your problem is with below code.

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                name="prefooter.subscribe"
                template="Magento_Theme::footer-subscribe.phtml" />
```

Because, you specify block name `name="prefooter.subscribe"` but there is a no block found like this name.

And if you want to change the position of your block then you can use `<move element="form.subscribe" destination="footer" before="-"/>` like this.

Click [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207015/move-newsletter-subscription-form-before-footer-magento-2) for more reference.

I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

> app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/myfooter-subscribe.phtml

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="my-custom-footersubscribe" template="Magento_Theme::html/myfooter-subscribe.phtml" />
```

Deploy the static-content, then Clean the cache.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

**Important :** check your phtml content, if you are calling some $block function from a module, it will not work.

In this case you create this phtml in that module then you call it in your layout like this:

```
<block class="{Vendor}\{Modulename}\Block\{Blockname}" name="my-custom-footersubscribe" template="Vendor_Modulename::html/myfooter-subscribe.phtml" />
```